# Executing shell script

Tags: gnome, scripts, 15.10, sh

I have a script:

```
echo "start"
cd ~/GoogleDrive/
drive push path-to-file/
echo "done"
```

which uploads path-to file to my Google Drive account. I can run this script without any problem by `sh UploadToDrive.sh` but when I try to execute it by means of double clicking on the script I get the error

```
start
/home/user/UploadToDrive.sh: 3: /home/user/UploadToDrive.sh: drive: not found
done
```

I posted it here because it seems like Gnome is doing something wrong rather than there is something wrong with the script, as it works when I use `sh` or `./` explicitly. I am using Ubuntu 15.10 with Gnome 3, if it is relevant.

Comment: What if you put `#!/bin/bash` on top?

Comment: Doesn't change anything. I get the same error.

Comment: How did you install this drive command? How is it added to the PATH?

Comment: Exactly how it says [here](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive)

Comment: What's the output of `which drive` and `echo "$PATH"` in your terminal. What's the output of `echo "$PATH"` from your script?

Answer (score 2):

Since that `.sh` extension is only a hint for users (yep linux doesnt dance in the line of doing extension yada yada like windows) your script lacks as first a shebang line, so you script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start"

#you might want to use explicit paths here this is why your script fails
cd /home/username/GoogleDrive/

#you might want to use explicit paths here this is why your script fails
drive push path-to-file/

echo "done"
```

After that change make sure your file has the proper permissions:

```
chmod 755 UploadToDrive.sh
```

And lastly enable execution within the GUI by going to the scripts properties:

[image: file-properties]

Comment: Well I've already allowed to be executed and I added the line above but the problem doesn't seem to go away.

Comment: did you as well `chmod` it ?

Comment: yup I did `chmod` it too

Comment: Have you tried a full path to 'drive'? @gonenc

Comment: Revised my answer @gonenc

Comment: When I used the explicit path to drive it suddenly worked? Any idea way it doesn't work this way

Comment: because you run the script in a sub-shell. And there the paths might not be the same as you see them in terminal or even in nautilus.